# Crontab Schedule when Raspberry Pi is off

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I want to delete some files every day at 6am. I was thinking about using crontab to schedule this task with something like

```
0 6 * * * sudo rm path/to/file
```

But my raspberry Pi will most likely be off at this time and turned on later during the day.

So my question is : If the RPi happens to be off while it should be executing the comand, does the task run at boot ?
I can't use `@reboot` because the raspberry can be powered off during the day and files should only be deleted once a day at 6am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The at and cron commands are only launched when the system date corresponds to the date scheduled for execution. There is no catch-up if the machine is turned off at the scheduled execution time.

a solution for you would be to code your own scheduling script and run it at daemon service

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bash script in crontab and file to store whether the file has been deleted or not. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=flag.txt
value=0

if test -f "$FILE"; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
    value=$(<$FILE) 
fi

echo "$value" 

if [ $value -eq 1 ]
then
echo "already deleted, nothing to do"
value=0
else
echo "not deleted, deleting"
rm file_to_delete.txt
value=1
fi

echo $value>$FILE
```

Then call this script `@reboot`